# Converting function with logic and ui into higher order functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to improve my JavaScript skills. I'm learning composability and functional patterns and I'm totally lost.

I have two functions: one mapping an array and the other called from within the previous function to generate the markup.

```
const names = ['peter', 'paul', 'patrice']

const namesMarkup = name => {
  return `<p>${name}</p>`
}

const showNames = listOfNames => {
  return listOfNames.map(el => {
    return namesMarkup(el)
  })
}

showNames(names)
```

I have been reading about HOF, which technically are functions that take a function as an argument and/or return a function.
How could I compose these functions to have a HOF?

I went through the basic examples like

```
const square = num => num * num

const plus10 = (num, callback) => {
  return callback(num) + 10
}

console.log(addTwo(7, square))
```

but I cannot make my mind around the previous example and working with lists.
I will appreciate help since the more I research the more confused I get.

Comment: Your existing code looks perfectly fine to me (though you can also consider implicit return)

Comment: you are just passing a function and invoking it which in the ends returns a result and you do some additional calculation with that result, there isn't too much science behind HOC

Comment: I'd simplify to `const showNames = listOfNames => listOfNames.map(namesMarkup);`. If you wanted to implement something higher-order here, you'd just be creating a wrapper around `map` which already is a higher-order method.

Comment: I mean, you *could* use a curried `map` wrapper to use partial application `const showNames = map(namesMarkup);` but you can overdo it. Also imo `showNames` is missing something like a `.join('\n')` in the end which would make currying futile.